# Codecademy javascript lesson 7/9 error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I've been stuck on 7/9 for 2 nights now. This is a rock, paper scissor game.  I can't figure out what is wrong. I tried the online lint and it also says my line 22 is an error(Expected an identifier and instead saw 'else'). Following the instructions I wrote another else if under the existing code inside the compare function.

my code :

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice ="rock"
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice ="paper";
} else {
    computerChoice ="scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare=function(choice1, choice2){
if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return("The result is a tie!");
}
else if(choice1 ==="rock"){
    if(choice2 ==="scissors")
    return("rock wins");
}
else{
    return"paper wins";
}
    else if(choice1 ==="paper");{
    if(choice2 ==="rock")
    return("paper wins");
}
else{
    return"scissors wins";
}
}
```

Comment: If you put it through [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and indent properly, I think it becomes a lot more obvious.

Comment: Just paste into the SO snippet editor and tidy

Comment: Simple syntax error. you have a semi-colon after your else if block. 
Also agreed. Indentation would making it much easier for you to catch such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing several syntax errors in your code.  It should look like the following:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
} 

console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return("The result is a tie!");
  } else if(choice1 === "rock") {
    if(choice2 === "scissors") {
      return("rock wins");
    } else {
      return "paper wins";
    }
  } else if(choice1 ==="paper") {
    if(choice2 ==="rock") {
      return("paper wins");
    } else {
      return"scissors wins";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 else if(choice1 ==="paper");{
    if(choice2 ==="rock")
    return("paper wins");
 }
```

you're terminating you're `else if` after the condition with `;`

it should be:

```
else if(choice1 ==="paper"){
        if(choice2 ==="rock")
        return("paper wins");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice ="rock"
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice ="paper";
} else {
    computerChoice ="scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare=function(choice1, choice2){
if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return("The result is a tie!");
}
else if(choice1 ==="rock"){
    if(choice2 ==="scissors")
    return("rock wins");
}
else{
    return"paper wins";
}
    else if(choice1 ==="paper");{ -- on this there is semicolon after elseif block.. and how come else if is there after else block.. 
    if(choice2 ==="rock")
    return("paper wins");
}
else{
    return"scissors wins";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are a beginner. Write a very clean code, take care of spaces and tabs, it is the best way to solve your debugging problems. there is indeed problem on line 22, you have put a semi-colon after a conditional statement.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if(computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock"
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return("The result is a tie!");
    } else if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if(choice2 === "scissors")
            return("rock wins");
    } else {
        return "paper wins";
    } else if(choice1 === "paper"){//here the error was.
        if(choice2 === "rock")
            return("paper wins");
    } else {
        return "scissors wins";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant have an `else if` after an `else` statement, thats what is causing your error message `error(Expected an identifier and instead saw 'else')`
And of course no semicolorn before the line really ends

https://jsfiddle.net/8hcpfnhw/

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice ="rock"
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice ="paper";
} else {
    computerChoice ="scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare=function(choice1, choice2){
if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return("The result is a tie!");
}
else if(choice1 ==="rock"){
    if(choice2 ==="scissors")
    return("rock wins");
}
else if(choice1 === "paper"){ // I changed this to else if instead of else
    return "paper wins";
}
else if(choice1 ==="paper") {
    if(choice2 ==="rock")
return("paper wins");
}
else{ // only else as last check
    return"scissors wins";
}
}
```